# PyQt5 QMenu no focus on exec_()

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have an already fully functioning app, with a custom widget that opens a custom QMenu when clicked, by calling exec_():

```
menu.exec_(QPoint)
```

I recently migrated from PyQt4->PyQt5 and noticed that the focusOutEvent method I was overriding was no longer responsive. I already have a fix, which works just fine:

```
menu.setFocus() #calling this prior to exec_()
```

Nevertheless, I would like to understand what exactly is different after the Qt migration, that I had to manually set the focus in order to keep desired functionality.

The menu is set to have StrongFocus.

Another apparent issue that might be related is that the setting of the cursor to hand fails to change back to regular cursor when the cursor leaves the menu rect.

Thank you! =)